# Somehow 'using' a list of types (in C++17 and up)

Tags: c++, templates, types, variadic-templates

How is is possible to make the following simple idea work?

```
template <typename ...Types>
void Function()
{ /* do something that depends on the Types */ }

void Test()
{

    using my_types = { int, float };    // not possible
    using my_types = int, float;        // alternative disallowed syntax
    Function<my_types>();
    
    Function<int,float>();              // OK, but I can't specify manually

}
```

**Why is there no direct support for this kind type lists? What's a simple workaround?**

Notes

- this is in a generic context, where I can't manually specify the types I want.
- I don't want to pass objects of these types to the function. They might be expensive or just not copyable.

**To clarify the use case**: The user defines a Trait-like class wherein he somehow specifies a list of types. Later, I need to process that list. How he specifies it is still open. So looking for a simple way to do that. No need for the overly complicated 'concat a type-list at compile-time' pattern that can be found here somewhere.

Comment: There are typelists, see any book on Template Metaprogramming in C++, template <class...Ts>
struct list
    {
    using type = list <Ts...>;    };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible alternative is define a sort of type wrapper (as `std::tuple` but that do absolutely nothing with template arguments)

```
template <typename...>
struct type_wrapper
 { };
```

and declare `Function()` receiving an object of that type

```
template <typename ...Types>
void Function (type_wrapper<Types...> const &)
{ /* do something that depends on the Types */ }
```

so you can pass an object of the desired wrapper to `Function()` and let template deduction works

```
using my_wrapped_types = type_wrapper<int, float>;

Function(my_wrapped_types{});
```

> Why is there no direct support for this kind type lists? What's a simple workaround?

Because there is `std::tuple` that cover most use cases and, as you can see, is trivial to write a wrapper when you want something lighter.

> I don't want to pass objects of these types to the function.

This way, you pass an object of type `type_wrapper` but no referenced type is instantiated.

Comment: Ahh, *facepalm* I'm already using this for another purpose in the same code. This time I failed to put my brain into backwards-logic mode. So you're saying that *because* the workaround/wrapper is so easy (i.e. 'straight-backward'), nobody ever cared to put something like `using types = A,B,...` in the standard!?

Comment: @non-user38741 - Yes, I suppose this is the reason. Adding that `std::tuple` cover a lot of use cases.

Comment: @non-user38741 - Regarding a possible `using types = A,B,...` syntax... no, the language doesn't support it so simple. I'm not a language layer so I don't know exactly why.

Comment: The necessity of creating and passing an object that is not really needed (other than deducing the types) is so counter-intuitive. (Not your fault, obviously. The answer is fine) If one could call `Function<type_wrapper<A,B>>()` and then access A and B somehow, that would be more of a forward-logic. Maybe that's possible with `tuple` as the wrapper.

Comment: @non-user38741 - Oh, yes: it's possible call `Function<type_wrapper<A, B>>()`. The problem is that you can't intercept (as template parameters of the function) `A` and `B`. You intercept `T = type_wrapper<A, B>`. Nothing forbid you to write some custom type traits to extract `A` and `B` from `T` but it's cumbersome. Better pass through a `class`/`struct` where, using partial specialization, you can intercept `A` and `B` in a simpler way (see Jarod42's answer).

Answer (score 2):

There are possible workarounds, mostly using `std::tuple`:

```
template <typename... Types>
void Function()
{ /* do something that depends on the Types */ }

template <typename... Types>
struct FunctionHelper<std::tuple<Types...>>
{ void operator ()() const { Function<Types...>(); } };

void Test()
{
    using my_types = std::tuple<int, float>;
    FunctionHelper<my_types>{}();
}
```

> I don't want to pass objects of these types to the function

Possible workaround is to use struct for that, as [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (C++20 but easily to rewrite)

and then

```
void Test()
{
    constexpr auto types = std::tuple{std::type_identity<int>{}, std::type_identity<float>{}};
    std::apply([](auto... args){ Function<typename decltype(args)::type...>(); }, types);
}
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, thanks. How could I not see that it's again tuple to the rescue!? (((you have a typo there with `using type` vs `<my_types>`)))

Comment: What about `Function<tuple<A,B>>()` and then have `std::apply` inside the function? Not my original specification, but that gets rid of `FunctionHelper`, or doesn't it? Are `A,B` not accessible then?

Comment: `std::apply`  expects `std::tuple` instance. So cannot be applied directly (as you said, types might be not default constructible).