# Is any of concept when using wrapper struct to hold list of types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Some of the code I'm writing is parameterized by a list of types, and, along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565789), I'm using a wrapper struct

```
template <typename... T>
struct types
{
};
```

so that I can write code like `using MyTypes = types<int, double>`, and then use `MyTypes` as a parameter to generate other types such as tuples of functions of the types.

I'm going to have functions that should only accept types in the list as a parameter. Hence what I'd like is to have a generic `concept IsAnyOfTypes`, so that I can write code like `template <typename T> concept MyType = IsAnyOfTypes<T, ListOfTypes >`. How can I write this concept in a simple way?

Ideally I'd like to connect this concept to / adopt a similar approach to `IsAnyOf` from [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as).

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
concept IsAnyOf = (std::same_as<T, U> || ...);
```

I have one working implementation that's using `std::tuple`, but I'd wanted a more direct approach, especially as I would prefer not to use recursive templates where I can avoid it.

```
template <template <typename> typename F, typename... T>
static std::tuple<F<T>...> tuple_of_f(types<T...>);
template <template <typename> typename F, typename Types>
using TupleOfF = decltype(tuple_of_f<F>(std::declval<Types>()));

template <typename T, typename Types>
concept IsAnyOfTypes = requires() { std::get<T>(std::declval<TupleOf<Types>>()); };
```

Comment: I read your question three times and still don't know what exactly you want to do. What does the `Types` template parameter of `IsAnyOfTypes` expect to accept?

Comment: It should be a types struct, e.g. `MyTypes` defined with `using MyTypes = types<int, double>`. The accepted answer perhaps puts it better than I did in my question :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want to create that concept:

```
template <typename T, typename Types>
concept IsAnyOfTypes = requires {
    {
        []<typename...Ts>(types<Ts...>){
            return std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<Ts, T> || ...)>{};
        }(Types{})
    } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};
```

With usage:

```
using MyTypes = types<int, double>;

static_assert(IsAnyOfTypes<int, MyTypes>);
static_assert(IsAnyOfTypes<double, MyTypes>);
static_assert(!IsAnyOfTypes<float, MyTypes>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s3dnE4drv)

Comment: Why not just use the value calculated by lambda directly like https://godbolt.org/z/qqcTzbjfe?

Comment: @康桓瑋: Because I miss it :)

Comment: Excellent -- if I understand this right, we need the integral / bool constant because the right hand side of the `->` can only check the _type_ of the return value from the lambda, i.e. a `constexpr` function simply returning `true` or `false` would not be sufficient?

Comment: @TooTone "*i.e. a `constexpr` function simply returning `true` or `false` would not be sufficient?*" In that case, the lambda can be evaluated using the nested `requires` like https://godbolt.org/z/sc7aTPx3a, which is basically equivalent to directly assigning the value returned by the lambda to the concept.